# WPF: родительское окно над дочерними

Tags: wpf, windows

В моем приложении имеется маленькое главное окно, из которого выполняется открытие и управление другими окнами приложения. Необходимо сделать, чтобы это окно не перекрывалось его дочерними окнами. Если же у дочерних окон в качестве Owner указывать это главное окно, очевидно, что оно будет ими перекрываться.

Что я пробовал:

1. Не выстраивать иерархию окон (оставлять пустым поле Owner у дочерних окон), а главному окну задать флаг TopMost=true. Но при этом рушится вся логика операционной системы при сворачивании/разворачивании окон, необходимо ее реализовывать самостоятельно. В этом случае появляется множество костылей по перехвату пользовательских операций. Имелись различные проблемы со сбросом флага TopMost при деактивации приложения.
2. Сделать скрытое родительское окно для всех окон, а при активации любого окна приложения указывать его в качестве Owner для главного окна. Тут тоже не обошлось без некоторых костылей, но на этом методе я в данный момент остановился. В принципе, он уже длительное время работает, но иногда WPF начинает сходить с ума - появляются исключения в его внутренних методах. Например, иногда говорит о том, что нельзя менять флаг IsVisiblity при закрытии окна, хотя у меня в код закрытия ни прямо, ни косвенно не работает с ним. Подозреваю, что это связано частой сменой значения Owner для главного окна, т.к. если не менять его, проблема не проявляется.

Сейчас активно рассматриваю вариант с одним прозрачным окном, развернутым на весь экран с Canvas и реализацией дочерних окон в виде элементов этого окна. Это решает практически все проблемы, но появляется другая - работа с несколькими мониторами (а окна приложения должны иметь возможность располагаться на разных мониторах). Особенно проблемным становится вариант, когда мониторы пользователя имеют разное разрешение и DPI.

Уверен, такая задача возникла не у меня первого. Подскажите, как ее можно решить еще? Нужно хотя бы общее направление.

Comment: Вам реально хочется странного, такой вот UI практически нигде не встречается. Обычно главное окно располагается _под_ всеми другими. Боюсь, вы идёте против логики Window Manager'а, а значит, вам придётся в той или иной мере его подменять.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае наиболее рационально будет всё же идти по первому пути (оставлять поле родителя пустым) и реализовывать логику сворачивания,  разворачивания и тд и тп самостоятельно. Например,  через события. Если вы реализовали MVVM, то логично и наиболее правильно будет обрабатывать и инициировать события при помощи mvvm-мессенджера. Какую из библиотек выбрать -  решайте сами. Если используете Prism,  то там уже есть встроенный мессенджер. Если обошлись без Prism и реализовали MVVM самостоятельно,  то попробуйте [EventBroker](http://www.appccelerate.com/eventbroker.html) от Appccelerate.

Comment: Мне тоже так показалось сначала, поэтому я с него и начал. Однако выявилась проблема со сбросом флага TopMost главного окна, когда пользователь переключается на другое приложение. Несмотря на то, что флаг сбрасывался, главное окно иногда оставалось на виду над окном другим приложением. Кроме этого, данный метод исключает возможность задания TopMost=true для всех окон приложения - а это необходимо для некоторых пользователей.
Работаю с чистым WPF, какие-либо библиотеки не используются.